# how to display the data in the table from the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

---

This code to calculate the age of the date of birth of the database, but the problem is when shown in the table, the location of that age are outside the table, can someone help me, this code

```
<?php
    include 'koneksi.php';
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pasien");
    function umur($tgl_lahir){
        $parts = split('-', $tgl_lahir);
        $thn_lahir='Year: ' + $parts[0];
        $bln_lahir='Month: ' + $parts[1];
        $tgl_lahir='Day: ' + $parts[2];
        $tanggal_today = date('d');
        $bulan_today=date('m');
        $tahun_today = date('Y');
        $harilahir=gregoriantojd($bln_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$thn_lahir);
        $hariini=gregoriantojd($bulan_today,$tanggal_today,$tahun_today);
        $umur=$hariini-$harilahir;
        $tahun=$umur/365; 
        $sisa=$umur%365; 
        $bulan=$sisa/30;
        $hari=$sisa%30;
        echo floor($tahun).",".floor($bulan);
    }
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

        echo"<table border='1px'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='50px'>".umur($row['tgl_lahir'])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo"</table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you view the parsed source of the page and look for that table, your error will be obvious. That will happen when you have HTML syntax issues.

Comment: can you send the snapshot of how your result looks?

Comment: Have you tried to put the <table> tag outside of the loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You're already `echo` the result of function `umur`. But in the function you are doing it one more time.

Change your `umur` function last line

```
echo floor($tahun).",".floor($bulan);
```

to

```
return floor($tahun).",".floor($bulan);
```

And move your `<table>` and `</table>` outside of `while`. Otherwise you would have a new table for every row.

Answer (score 1):

Just move `echo"<table border='1px'>";` before `while` loop and move 
`echo"</table>";` after `while` loop.

Update your code to

```
<?php
include 'koneksi.php';
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pasien");
function umur($tgl_lahir)
{
    $parts = split('-', $tgl_lahir);
    $thn_lahir='Year: ' + $parts[0];
    $bln_lahir='Month: ' + $parts[1];
    $tgl_lahir='Day: ' + $parts[2];
    $tanggal_today = date('d');
    $bulan_today=date('m');
    $tahun_today = date('Y');
    $harilahir=gregoriantojd($bln_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$thn_lahir);
    $hariini=gregoriantojd($bulan_today,$tanggal_today,$tahun_today);
    $umur=$hariini-$harilahir;
    $tahun=$umur/365; 
    $sisa=$umur%365; 
    $bulan=$sisa/30;
    $hari=$sisa%30;
    return floor($tahun).",".floor($bulan);
}


echo"<table border='1px'>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{ 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='50px'>".umur($row['tgl_lahir'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['nama']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
```

It is recommended to use `return` instead of `echo` in function to return the value. You can use `echo umur($row['tgl_lahir']);` to print the returned value of function.

Comment: It fould still print age outside of `<table>`.

Comment: @ReneKorss I have not tested the output.

Comment: Okay. You need to replace `echo` with `return` in function.

Answer (score 0):

try this: You need to return the value from the function rather than echo it

```
<?php
    include 'koneksi.php';

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pasien");
    function umur($tgl_lahir){
        $parts = split('-', $tgl_lahir);
        $thn_lahir='Year: ' + $parts[0];
        $bln_lahir='Month: ' + $parts[1];
        $tgl_lahir='Day: ' + $parts[2];
        $tanggal_today = date('d');
        $bulan_today=date('m');
        $tahun_today = date('Y');
        $harilahir=gregoriantojd($bln_lahir,$tgl_lahir,$thn_lahir);
        $hariini=gregoriantojd($bulan_today,$tanggal_today,$tahun_today);
        $umur=$hariini-$harilahir;
        $tahun=$umur/365; 
        $sisa=$umur%365; 
        $bulan=$sisa/30;
        $hari=$sisa%30;
        return floor($tahun).",".floor($bulan);
    }
    echo"<table border='1px'>";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='50px'>".umur($row['tgl_lahir'])."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nama']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo"</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't give a code like it without explanation. It's not very usefull for the question owner and for later reader.